# Replace file inside layout folder and java folder (android studio)

Tags: java, file, android-studio, replace, path

How to replace some files in running app (main activity files), e.g.,

> /src/main/java/[com.package.name]/home.java 
>   /src/main/res/layout/home.xml

with other files:

> /src/main/assets/home.java 
>   /src/main/assets/home.xml

I've tried:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    alertDialog.show();

    if (result.length() == 5) {
        String sourcePath1 = "/src/main/assets/activity_home.xml";
        File source1 = new File(sourcePath1);
        String sourcePath2 = "/src/main/assets/home.java";
        File source2 = new File(sourcePath2);

        String destinationPath1 = "/src/main/res/layout/activity_home.xml";
        File destination1 = new File(destinationPath1);
        String destinationPath2 = "/src/main/java/cz/oscio/oscioosp/home.java";
        File destination2 = new File(destinationPath2);
        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(source1, destination1);
            FileUtils.copyFile(source2, destination2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work, I suspect wrong file path. And if I try:

```
getAssets().open("activity_home.xml")   //Cannot resolve method 'getAssets()'
```

but this wouldn't help in `/src/main/res/layout/` case anyway...

EDIT: It has to be done only once - it will change app itself, updated code.

REPORT:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/src/main/assets/activity_home.xml' does not exist 
>         at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:636)
>         at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:606)
>         at cz.oscio.oscioosp.logging.onPostExecute(logging.java:112)
>         at cz.oscio.oscioosp.logging.onPostExecute(logging.java:33) 
>         at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651) 
>         at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java) 
>         at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Your path starts with a "/" or a "./" ? Because it will be interpreted differrently

Comment: I suggest my path starts in app, so I just went from app folder... (like C:/Users/Public/MYAPP/app/src/main/assets/home.xml ) and therefore I've used  /src/main...

Comment: What I mean is, if your path starts with `/`, it may (will probably) be interpreted as a non-relative path, i.e. starting from your home directory. Have you tried putting the absolute path (C:/Users/Public/MYAPP/app/src/main/assets/home.xml) ?

Comment: Nah, it's not a solution since this app has to run on mobile phone, I need to start in apk folder (of installed app)... Isn't problem that my layout folder already contains the same named file? I want new one to replace it...

Comment: How would you find path from app-root folder? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I wasn't proposing to do this as a fix, but as a debugging: you said "I suspect wrong file path", that means you're not sure it comes from here.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure, so I don't know If it's the right way how to get file path...

Comment: What I am saying is: test with absolute paths first, to be sure the problem comes from here. BTW you have twice `File source = new File(sourcePath);` but never `File destination`

Comment: it's only mistake with creating this thread :( I saw there is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for accesing files out of installed apk folder, but nowhere found something for accesing INside, so I tried this hardcore string...

Comment: I have a plausible explanation. You're creating `File destination` and `File source` with the same sourcepath, as it is still in the thread, so you copy from the file to itself? Also, if it's not that, please post your error stacktrace.

Comment: So i did some research and I discovered, that nothing in if condition works,  so IF condition is supposed to be wrong. BUT when I tried `System.out.println(result);` it returns "done" and result.contentEquals("done") is false??

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/48ZqV

Comment: I managed to get over it with `.length()` and above is error report

Comment: I posted my answer. Let me know if you could fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace is eloquent: `'/src/main/assets/activity_home.xml' does not exist`. The file is not found, thus the treatments on it will throw an exception.

You can check the current directory of your application using `System.getProperty("user.dir");`. But unless you changed it with some specific methods, the directory should be the root directory of your application.

Your path should be correct (as far as I can tell), but as I said in a comment, you shouldn't start your path by a `/`, as the path will be interpreted as an **absolute path**, i.e. starting from your **computer root directory**. Instead, your path should be `src/main/assets/activity_home.xml`.

Comment: thanks, `src/main/assets/activity_home.xml ` is much better :)

Comment: @Jiří You're welcome. Now I realize I should be more clear in my comments: the first comment I posted was pointing out the same thing as this answer (i.e., relative paths vs absolute paths), and it was 18 hours ago :p Have a nice day!

Comment: Nah I didn't check my if condition at first, and already thought I have my string wrong... even thought it WAS wrong, at first, nothing worked because of false if condition (although I still don't know why it returned false, but `.lenght()` helped ... cause `System.out.println(result.lenght());` returned 5 and `System.out.println(result);` returned done... but now it works :)